# How can I direct log4j output so that different log levels go to different appenders?

Tags: log4j

Is it possible to have "debug" and "info" output written to the console while the "info" output is only written to some log file?  For example, given this logging:

```
LOG.debug(fileContent);
LOG.info(fileLength);
```

What does a corresponding `log4j.xml` look like?

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I've got it now:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        ...
    </appender>

    <appender name="otherAppender"
              class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender FileAppender">
       <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        ...
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority     value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="otherAppender" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

That is definitely possible. The configuration would look something like this (not checked for syntactic correctness):

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        ...
    </appender>

    <appender name="otherAppender"
              class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender FileAppender">
        ...
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mycompany.mypackage.MyClass">
        <level        value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="otherAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority     value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

All debug and info messages go to the `console` appender. Info messages go to `otherAppender`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [this](http://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/log4j/log4j.html#LOG4J-Basics-Basics-Example-consandpatt) page for some examples.

It's as simple as adding two different appenders to your program, one appender for each type of logging you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

With the configuration from Eddie I can only get the "info" output for MyClass. But what I would like to have is that the "info" output of MyClass goes to a file AND the "debug" output of MyClass goes to console.

Answer (score 0):

Do as rwwilden suggested but remove this part:

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.mypackage.MyClass">
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="otherAppender" />
</logger>
```

And add `<param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>` under the otherAppender.