# Log4j different appenders for different log levels using properties file

Tags: configuration, log4j, appender

Since the official documentation for log4j is a [broken link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/docs/documentation.html), and the getting started guide isn't helping me, I would like to know how to use two appenders with different log levels for the same logger, using a `.properties` file instead of an `.xml` one.

For example, like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug,  APPENDER_FILE, APPENDER_STDOUT
```

I'm logging with two different appenders, but on the same log level (`DEBUG`). I would like to use an `INFO` log level for `APPENDER_STDOUT`, and a`DEBUG` log level for `APPENDER_FILE`.

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751431/how-can-i-direct-log4j-output-so-that-different-log-levels-go-to-different-appen), but unlike that question, I'm using the `log4j.properties` file, not the xml file.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to set the *logger* to the more detailed of the two levels (DEBUG) but then set a threshold on the *appender* to tell it to only show messages at INFO and above

```
log4j.appender.APPENDER_STDOUT.Threshold=INFO
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to specify the appender at the package level, you can use:

```
log4j.logger.[package]=[Level], [Appender]
```

Example:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=INFO, MyAppender
```

For more details, please, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19795886/679240