# log4j - How to limit the log of a package/class for an appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, htmlunit, appender

I am using the log4j.properties, and I have an appender called RDev.

I want set the level of RDev appender to DEBUG except for specific packages (HTMLUnit in my case)

My current log4j.properties is like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug RDev, test

log4j.appender.RDev=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RDev.File=D:/logs

log4j.appender.RDev.MaxFileSize=5mb
log4j.appender.RDev.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.RDev.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RDev.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p %d{MMM/dd HH:mm:ss}] [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

and I want to filter/remove the DEBUG log of these packages:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit
org.apache.commons.httpclient
org.apache.http.impl.conn
```

**UPDATE ** I tried this and it works for all appendars:

```
# Set specific logger levels.
log4j.logger.org.mortbay.log=fatal
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=fatal
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.headers=fatal
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=fatal
```

(from https://code.google.com/p/spidey/wiki/HtmlUnitErrors)

Now the question is how to limit this configs to one appendar? (not all of them)
(e.g. I want to see the debugs in the file, not console.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still want to see log lines for levels that are above DEBUG for those packages?  If so, [this log4j tutorial](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) from Apache describes one way to do that; look a bit more than halfway down, at the text that reads "Suppose we are no longer interested in seeing the output of any component belonging to the com.foo package."

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619754/log4j-different-appenders-for-different-log-levels-using-properties-file should address the updated part of your question.