# How to use the same logger to log different levels to console + logfile?

Tags: java, web-services, log4j, cxf

I have a log4j logger that currently writes the log both to console and to a file, which works fine.

Later I'd like to configure it to log INFO + ERROR to the logfile, but only show ERROR on console. What would I have to change to achieve this?

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console, MyFileAppender

log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=INFO, console
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor=INFO, console
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor=INFO, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out

log4j.appender.MyFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.File=c:/logs.log
```

Further, I'd like to prevent the CXF XML requests to be logged in the file. But I want them still to be shown in the console. How?

Comment: try changing **log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=INFO, console** to **log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=WARN, MyFileAppender**  i think the rootLogger is automatically logging everything in INFO on both appenders.  you can probably override at a package level.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Appender based configuration

Configuring the log levels per each appender has to be done separately unless it is same as the root level configuration. Below sample `log4.properties` file is configured to log `INFO` and above into the console, but only `ERROR` and above into the file.

```
log4j.appender.[appender-name].Threshold=[Level]
```

Look at the last line of the below example (from "[How to integrate log4j with your Java project](http://www.digizol.com/2013/10/log4j-how-to-integrate-with-your-java.html)").

```
# root level configurations 
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,console,file   

# configuration for console outputs  
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender  
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  

# configuration for file output (into a file named messages.log)  
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.file.File=messages.log  
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 

# threshold for file output 
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=ERROR
```

## Package based log levels

Any of the followings will help.

```
log4j.logger.[package]=[Level]
log4j.logger.[package]=[Level], [Appender]
```

As an example:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=INFO, console
```

Answer (score 4):

As per [this SO question (and its answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619754/log4j-different-appenders-for-different-log-levels-using-properties-file) you have to set a threshold on your appenders:

```
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=ERROR

log4j.appender.MyFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.File=c:/logs.log
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.Threshold=INFO
```